# Code Igniter: Tank_auth config is initialised automatically

Tags: php, codeigniter

Iam using default settings for tank_auth installation. When I tried following statement in controller:

```
$this->load->library('tank_auth');
```

It shows following output:

```
This is Tank Auth Conf

This is Tank Auth Library-INITIAL

This is Tank Auth Library-BEFORE

This is Tank Auth Conf

This is Tank Auth Library-AFTER
This is login page in User Folder after USER_CONTROLLER-2
```

following is __construct function from library file of tank_auth:

```
function __construct()
{
       echo '<br>This is Tank Auth Library-INITIAL<br>';

            $this->ci =& get_instance();

            echo '<br>This is Tank Auth Library-BEFORE<br>';

    $this->ci->load->config('tank_auth', TRUE);

    $this->ci->load->library('session');
    $this->ci->load->database();
    $this->ci->load->model('tank_auth/users');

    // Try to autologin
    $this->autologin();

            echo '<br>This is Tank Auth Library-AFTER<br>';
}
```

Following lines are added in config file of tank_auth:

```
echo '<br>This is Tank Auth Conf<br>';
```

Can some one guide me why config file is initialising two times.

Note: There is no entry in autoload file.
Tank_auth versrion :1.0.9. 
Code Igniter version: 2.0.2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CI automatically loads the corresponding config file (if it exists) before loading a library. See the `_ci_init_class` function (Loader.php, line 919).

As your code shows, Tank Auth loads the config file a second time in its constructor, but that one is redundant since CI does it automatically.